# Structs and passing values to them

Tags: c, struct

If i had an array such as int numbers[5] i could assign values to it with numbers[0] = 1 or numbers[3] = 4. Then if i had a struct such as

```
struct structName
{
    int number0;
    int number1;
    int number2;
};
```

is there any way to do something like the following (note this is not working code)

```
int main(void)
{
    struct structName name;  //how could i declare this to do the following
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        name[i] = i;  //maybe  name.[i]
    }
}
```

so is there a way to write name[ variable ] = someNumber  to assign someNumber to say number0 (if variable was 0) or number2 (if variable was 2). ive  been looking for days and cant find anything that does this. (maybe i just don't know what to look for)

Comment: if `struct structName { int num[3]; };` then `name.num[i] = i;`

Comment: http://ideone.com/x1pz4Z

Answer (score 5):

> is there any way to do something like the following

No, there's no way to access the fields of the structure by index. You use the names of the fields instead:

```
struct structName name;
name.number0 = someNumber;
name.number1 = someOtherNumber;
```

If you want to access the values by index, use an array instead, even if it's embedded in the structure:

```
struct structName
{
    int numbers[3];
    // other fields here
};
```

Then you can say:

```
struct structName name;
for (int i = 0; i <= 2, i++) {
    name.numbers[i] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write a function which uses a switch statement that allows you to access fields by index. Something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct structName{
    int number0;
    int number1;
    int number2;
};

void assign(struct structName * name, int i, int j){
    switch(i){
        case 0:
            name->number0 = j;
            break;
        case 1:
            name->number1 = j;
            break;
        case 2:
            name->number2 = j;
            break;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int i;
    struct structName name;
    for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        assign(&name,i,i);
    }
    //test:
    printf("%d\n",name.number0);
    printf("%d\n",name.number1);
    printf("%d\n",name.number2);
    return 0;
}
```

(which prints 0,1,2 as expected).

Needless to say, there isn't much point in doing this (as opposed to just having a field which is an array) *unless* the struct in question is already defined as part of an API or already part of a code base which isn't easily refactored.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that @BLUEPIXY has hidden a macro solution to OP's problem behind a link in a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with some weird and inadvisable memory manipulation. You're much better off using an array.

```
struct structName
{
    int numbers[3];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct structName name;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        name.numbers[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Also note that you had some syntax errors in your `for` loop and an off-by-one error.

Answer (score -1):

Macros with arguments should work

```
#define name(x) x
```

So name(1) would become 1. name(2) would become 2 and so on.

Comment: How exactly do you propose to use this macro to assign a value to, e.g., the `number2` field of OP's `struct`?

Answer (score -1):

In C, there is no spoon.

```
struct structName name;
int *idx = &name; // First we need a memory address to the struct
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(name) / sizeof(*idx); ++i) {
    // idx[i] == name.numberX
    idx[i] = i;
}
```

Now, if you check the values of name.number0, name.number1, name.number2 you will see they contain the correct values.

This is not a very good way of doing things with structs, but I felt compelled to answer after the top response claims it is impossible.

Comment: This solution may or may not work-- `struct`s may contain padding, which you do not account for. This is an implementation-dependent detail.

Comment: The struct is 3 integers only which contains no padding. As long as the index is carefully managed you can always access struct data by index. Just, in this case it was best to iterate by the size of an integer.